# Large Time quantum vs small quantum for CPU Scheduling?

Tags: c, cpu, scheduling, round-robin

What are the main differences (and advantages/disadvantages) between using a large time quantum or a small time quantum in respect to round robin CPU scheduling?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Round Robin Scheduling the time quantum is fixed and then processes are scheduled such that no process get CPU time more than one time quantum in one go.

If time quantum is too large, the response time of the processes is too much which may not be tolerated in interactive environment.

If time quantum is too small, it causes unnecessarily frequent context switch leading to more overheads resulting in less throughput.

In this paper a method using fuzzy logic has been proposed that decides a value that is neither too large nor too small such that every process has got reasonable response time and the throughput of the system is not decreased due to unnecessarily context switches.

Edit: Link to article referenced: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4741092/

Comment: I guess you've forgotten to link the paper.